# How to get all days in current week in swift

Tags: swift, date, calendar

I am making an application where I need to get the day of the year for all days in the current week.
To achieve this, I am looking for a result similar to below (Today is Thursday the 23rd of March)

```
Monday = 79
Tuesday = 80
Wednesday = 81
Thursday = 82
Friday = 83
```

Saturday and Sunday can be included, however my application only needs weekdays rather then weekends. Today is day 82

Comment: You haven't written any code that you have tried. This isn't the best of questions because of that, but check this out [NSDateFormatter Info](http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/). Also, there are `year % 4 == 0 ? year % 100 == 0 ? year % 200 == 0 ? 29 : 28 : 29 : 28` days in February if you were wondering.

Comment: I sense that this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week) article will help as well. I don't feel like writing any code for it, but you got me researching the different ways. I am sure Calendar has some easy way to achieve this without digging too deep though.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To get the weekdays of the week, it is:

```swift
let calendar = Calendar.current
let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
let dayOfWeek = calendar.component(.weekday, from: today)
let dates = calendar.range(of: .weekday, in: .weekOfYear, for: today)!
    .compactMap { calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0 - dayOfWeek, to: today) }
    .filter { !calendar.isDateInWeekend($0) }
```

To display that as “Thursday = 82”, it is:

```swift
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "eeee' = 'D"
for date in dates {
    print(formatter.string(from: date))
}
```

Or

```swift
let strings = dates.map { formatter.string(from: $0) }
```

---

If you want it to consider `firstWeekday` (generally only a concern if you are no longer filtering weekends out of the results, hence no `filter` on `isDateInWeekend`, below):

```swift
let calendar = Calendar.current
let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
let todaysDayOfWeek = calendar.component(.weekday, from: today)
guard
    let weekdaysRange = calendar.range(of: .weekday, in: .weekOfYear, for: today),
    let index = weekdaysRange.firstIndex(of: calendar.firstWeekday)
else { return }
let weekdays = weekdaysRange[index...] + weekdaysRange[..<index].map { $0 + weekdaysRange.count }
let dates = weekdays.compactMap { calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0 - todaysDayOfWeek, to: today) }
```

Comment: So if I wanted to get that as a variable, I would the. Have to get the calendar component?

Comment: If you want an array of those strings, you'd lose the `for` loop and just do `let strings = days.map { formatter.string(from: $0) }`

Comment: How would I do that for all days in the current month?

Comment: @Rob Why not just `weekdays.compactMap`? Upper bound is not included anyway when you iterate over a Range.

Comment: Or just retire `weekdays` entirely, as above.

Comment: Is it possible to respect the firstWeekday setting in the calendar? Mine is on monday but this function always starts on sunday.

Comment: @andredewaard See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/9f9e40352a2fa2f4d2900f4b15b1ecff. Also revised the above to show how to factor `firstWeekday`.

Answer (score 13):

I had problems with adapting Rob's solution for when the week starts on Monday. This solution adapts to your `calendar.firstWeekday` setting.

```
var calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
calendar.firstWeekday = 2 // Start on Monday (or 1 for Sunday)
let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
var week = [Date]()
if let weekInterval = calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, for: today) {
    for i in 0...6 {
        if let day = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: i, to: weekInterval.start) {
            week += [day]
        }
    }
}
return week
```

Comment: I believe that `firstWeekday` returns the correct number depending on the region that is set.  That is why you do `Calendar.current` or `Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent`.

Comment: `calendar.local = Locale(identifier: "ES")` as an example.

Answer (score 7):

I made a small extension on Calendar, which might be helpful for anyone else looking for a more functional solution to this.

```
import Foundation

extension Calendar {
  func intervalOfWeek(for date: Date) -> DateInterval? {
    dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, for: date)
  }

  func startOfWeek(for date: Date) -> Date? {
    intervalOfWeek(for: date)?.start
  }

  func daysWithSameWeekOfYear(as date: Date) -> [Date] {
    guard let startOfWeek = startOfWeek(for: date) else {
      return []
    }

    return (0 ... 6).reduce(into: []) { result, daysToAdd in
      result.append(Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: daysToAdd, to: startOfWeek))
    }
    .compactMap { $0 }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also use enumerateDates like this:

```
func getAllDaysOfTheCurrentWeek() -> [Date] {
    var dates: [Date] = []
    guard let dateInterval = Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear,
                                                           for: Date()) else {
        return dates
    }
    
    Calendar.current.enumerateDates(startingAfter: dateInterval.start,
                                    matching: DateComponents(hour:0),
                                    matchingPolicy: .nextTime) { date, _, stop in
            guard let date = date else {
                return
            }
            if date <= dateInterval.end {
                dates.append(date)
            } else {
                stop = true
            }
    }
    
    return dates
}
```

Comment: It returns 6 days a week.

Comment: @ShourobDatta Fixed it.