# How to set weekdays date in CollectionView starting from Monday to Saturday in swift

Tags: ios, swift, weekday

I have to show weekdays date in CollectionView start from Monday to Saturday. Until the end of the week, I have to show that weekdays date only. My task image [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi950.png). Please help/advise me how to do this task.

I am getting weekdays but its start from current day, But i need start date from monday,

```
func arrayOfDates() -> NSArray {

        let numberOfDays: Int = 6
        let formatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd"
        let startDate = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var offset = DateComponents()
        var dates: [Any] = [formatter.string(from: startDate)]

        for i in 1..<numberOfDays {
            offset.day = i
            let nextDay: Date? = calendar.date(byAdding: offset, to: startDate)
            let nextDayString = formatter.string(from: nextDay!)
            dates.append(nextDayString)
        }
        return dates as NSArray
    }
```

Comment: Hi Martin R thank you. I edited my code plese check it

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42981665/1187415.

Comment: Yeah, your answer is fine but I need 6 days but here it's giving only 5 days. if I remove  .filter { !calendar.isDateInWeekend($0) } it's showing 7 days and its starting from sunday. How to show Monday is start date

Comment: You also need to set calendar.firstWeekday = 2 to start on Monday.  The firstWeekday property tells you what day of the week the week starts in your locale.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func formattedDaysInThisWeekNet() -> [String]
{
    // create calendar
    let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!

    // today's date
    let today = NSDate()

    let weekday = calendar.component(.weekday, from: today as Date)
    let beginningOfWeek : NSDate
    if weekday != 2 { // if today is not Monday, get back
        beginningOfWeek = calendar.nextDate(after: today as Date, matching: .weekday, value: 1, options: [.matchNextTime, .searchBackwards])! as NSDate
    } else { // today is Monday
        beginningOfWeek = calendar.startOfDay(for: today as Date) as NSDate
    }
    var formattedDays = [String]()
    for i in 0..<7 {
        let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: i, to: beginningOfWeek as Date, options: [])!
        formattedDays.append(formatDate(date: date as NSDate))
        let firstDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: beginningOfWeek as Date, options: [])!
        let lastDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: beginningOfWeek as Date, options: [])!
        let fullString = "\(formatDateFull(date: firstDate as NSDate)) - \(formatDateFull(date: lastDate as NSDate))" as String
        fulldateLbl.text = "<  \(fullString)  >"
        print(fullString)
    }
    return formattedDays
}
```

Comment: Thank you teja_D. But it's giving only Monday date. I need 6 days a week

Comment: Call this function where you want to use weekdays

Comment: are you able to figure out this? @Ram

Comment: This line         formattedDays.append(formatDate(date: date as NSDate))

Comment: I completed this task. Thank you teja_D.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Days: Int {
    case Sat = 0, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri
    static var all = [Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat]
}

func getWeekDays(date: Date) -> [Date] {
    var weekDates = [Date]()

    let cal = Calendar.current
    var comps = cal.dateComponents([.weekOfYear, .yearForWeekOfYear], from: date)
    let days = Days.all
    for day in days {
        comps.weekday = day.rawValue
        weekDates.append(cal.date(from: comps)!)
    }
    return weekDates
}

    print(getWeekDays(date: Date()))  // print all dates from Monday to Saturday
```

Comment: Thank you @Atif Khan. But i ma getting 7 days . And i need start from Monday

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys thank you for your response. I completed This task.

```
func arrayOfDates() -> NSArray {

    var calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
    let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
    let dayOfWeek = calendar.component(.weekday, from: today) - calendar.firstWeekday
    let weekdays = calendar.range(of: .weekday, in: .weekOfYear, for: today)!
    let dayss = (weekdays.lowerBound ..< weekdays.upperBound)
        .compactMap { calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0 - dayOfWeek, to: today) }
    //.filter { !calendar.isDateInWeekend($0) }

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd"

    let strings = dayss.map { formatter.string(from: $0) }
    self.dates = strings as NSArray
    return dates as NSArray
}
```

But here I have one question, How to disable the previous dates. I need to select only current date and next dates.

Comment: I am printing only date like todays date 25 but i need this Date formate: 2018-10-25. If i change this formate i cant show whole formate in collectionViewCell. Plese some one help me.