# How to get all weekend dates from a year [saturday and sunday] by passing a particular year in swift?

Tags: swift

How to get all weekend dates [saturday and sunday] by passing a particular year in swift? Say for as an example, if I pass 2018 it will return [6/1/18]

Comment: See answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981665/how-to-get-all-days-in-current-week-in-swift

Comment: It is not giving an exact answer i am looking for if i pass an year 2018 it will the return the saturday and sunday dates starting from the month of Jan to dec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of days in year, iterate through them using compactMap, check if each day is in weekend, if positive return it otherwise return nil:

```
extension Date{
    var year: Int {
        return Calendar.current.component(.year, from: self)
    }
    var weekendsInSameYear: [Date] {
        return Calendar.current.range(of: .day, in: .year, for: self)?.compactMap {
            guard let date = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: year, day: $0).date, Calendar.current.isDateInWeekend(date) else {
                return nil
            }
            return date
        } ?? []

    }
}
```

---

```
let dates = Date().weekendsInSameYear
for date in dates {
    print(date.description(with: .current))
}

//  "Saturday, January 6, 2018 at 12:00:00 AM Brasilia Summer Time"
//  "Sunday, January 7, 2018 at 12:00:00 AM Brasilia Summer Time"
//  "..."
//  "Saturday, December 29, 2018 at 12:00:00 AM Brasilia Summer Time"
//  "Sunday, December 30, 2018 at 12:00:00 AM Brasilia Summer Time"
```

Comment: What about using `nextWeekend()` and `dateIntervalOfWeekend()` to “jump” to the next weekend, instead of iterating over all days?

Comment: @MartinR that’s a good idea but I don’t think performance would be an issue here

Comment: Why the above code is not working in iOS 9.0 and below Versions?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean but you are probably printing utc time